# Change padding color of Label widget in ttk / python

Tags: python, tkinter, styling, ttk

I am trying to display an image with ttk/tkinter in python. The image has a white border, and I want to display this image on a larger white background - so it has lots of white space around.

For this I use "padx" and "pady" in the label with 100px each. Unfortunately the padding area is gray.

Now I tried changing the label's foreground and background color to no avail. The padding area stays gray. Then I put the label in a Frame widget, and tried changing the Frame's foreground/background color. But unfortunately the Frame widget does not listen to width= and height= arguments. Also if I change the foreground color the SUNKEN border changes color - really cool, but totally useless for me :/ .

Could anybody help me with this? The current nonworking code looks like this:

```
style = Style()

style.configure('Dlr.TFrame', background="blue", relief=SUNKEN)
frm = Frame(self, style="Dlr.TFrame") # does not work: ,height=500,width=500)
frm.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=8, columnspan=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)

style.configure("Dlr.TLabel", background="white")
style.configure("Dlr.TLabel.padding", background="white") # just guessed ...
self.IMG = Label(frm, style="Dlr.TLabel")
self.IMG.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=100, pady=100)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your technique for putting the image inside a frame and then setting the frame color is the right technique.

The width and height don't work because both `grid` and `pack` cause the containing widget to "shrink-to-fit" by default. This is called geometry propagation. You can turn this feature on or off using the methods [grid_propagate](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_propagate-method) or [pack_propagate](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm#Tkinter.Pack.pack_propagate-method) on the containing widget.

For example, if you call `frm.grid_propagate(False)` and then set the widget and height of `frm`, the width and height will be honored.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've got mixed results with this - or gGood news and bad news. Good news is that I made the frame grow to a fixed size with `grid_propagate(false)`. Bad news is that the background is still gray, _and_ now the image is in the top-left corner of the frame.
New code:
`style.configure('Dlr.TFrame', relief=RAISED, bg="white") # bg does not work
frm = Frame(self, style="Dlr.TFrame", width=500, height=500)
frm.grid_propagate(False)
frm.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=10, columnspan=2)
# no changes on image/label, just removed the padx/y`

Comment: you have to use the full keyword "background" not just "bg" as you posted above.